# Service+AsyncTask - how to really stop the the Task?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I have trouble ending an AsyncTask, even though IMHO, I have adhered to the recommended flagging practice. The code below only takes the BackButton into account, but to have a general solution for all kinds of exiting the activity would be best.

I have a MeasurementLoadingsScreen Class which binds a Service like this:

```
ServiceConnection _connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            _service = myService.Stub.asInterface(iBinder);
            runMeasurementAsyncTask();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            _service = null;
        }
    };

 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
        serviceIntent.setPackage(myService.class.getPackage().getName());
        serviceIntent.setAction(myService.class.getName() + ".ACTION_BIND");
        bindService(serviceIntent, _connection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_measurement_loadingscreen);
        findViewsById();
        setDefaultVisibility();

        intent = getIntent();
       //myStuff
    }
```

The MeasurementLoadingScreen contains an AsyncTask with a WeakReference (or SoftReference, tried both).

```
private void runMeasurementAsyncTask() {
 //myStuff
        meTask = new MeasurementTask(this);
        meTask.execute();
    }

private static class MeasurementTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
        private WeakReference<MeasurementLoadingScreen> activityReference;
        private ServiceHelper serviceHelper;
       //myStuff
        public static boolean isRunning = false;


        MeasurementTask(MeasurementLoadingScreen context) {
            activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
            serviceHelper = new ServiceHelper(context._service);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            MeasurementLoadingScreen activityReference = this.activityReference.get();
            isRunning = true;
            //myStuff, it's ok to finish running this before cancelling
            if (isCancelled()) {
                return "cancelled";
            }
            // more myStuff
            if (isCancelled()) {
                return "cancelled";
            }

           [...]

 @Override
        protected void onCancelled(){
          //myStuff: safely shutdown measurement process, might take a few seconds at worst
            meTask.isRunning = false;

            if(activityReference.get() != null) {
                activityReference.get().finish();  //it does not work without this, either
            }
          super.onCancelled();
        }
```

When I tap back twice (regardless of specific behaviour), it should (safely) abort the AsyncTask:

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if (mBackPressed + TIME_INTERVAL > System.currentTimeMillis())
        {
            if (meTask == null) {
                super.onBackPressed();
                return;
            }
            cancelTask();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cancelling Task", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        else { Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tap back button in order to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }

        mBackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (_connection != null)
        unbindService(_connection);
        finish();//
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        int i = 0;
        super.onPause();
//poll state of task here
        finish();
    }
```

I cannot seem to get the Task to stop running. If I set the meTask =null; in onPause, for example, it will eventually go through onCancelled and then call onStop, ending the service as well. But there is no way of waiting for the onCancelled to do its stuff and notify me with the isRunningflag, getStatus or whatever. The app just freezes however I poll the Task, which stays RUNNING all the time, unless I set it to null (undesirable, of course).

Edit:
I have added a polling attempt that allows the activity to call onPause/onStop eventually, but my main issue is with the polling, I do not ever see a finished/finishing task, even though onCancelled gets called at some point, but only after I set the meTask = null;, it does not continue cancelling normally.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        int i=0;
        if (mBackPressed + TIME_INTERVAL > System.currentTimeMillis())
        {
            if (meTask == null) {
                super.onBackPressed();
                return;
            }
            cancelTask();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cancelling Task", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            while ((meTask.getStatus()== AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) && (i < 20000)) {
//waiting etc., checking für isRunning doesn't work either
                i++;
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "meTask  " + meTask.getStatus());
            meTask = null;
            Log.d(TAG, "meTask null after " + i);
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;

Edit 2:
Content of cancelTask()
private void cancelTask() {
        if (meTask != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Async Task Cancel... ");
            meTask.cancel(true);
        }
    }
```

Edit 3: 
Regardless of where I put the cancel(true), e.g. onPause, onStop, the Task stays alive and only gives me the Log output of

```
    if (isCancelled()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Cancel after XYZ");
            return "cancelled";
    }
```

and

```
@Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
            isRunning = false;
            Log.d(TAG, "...Async Task Cancelled ");
        }
```

at the very end, after onPause, onStop, onDestroy have finished. I am at my wits end. It is not surprising that the Task continues to run for a bit, but it must stop before the service in unbound. How can I wait for the task to finish?

Comment: You should make a helper method to connect ```onBackPressed()``` with the ```AsyncTask<onStop()>``` method. [Check out the documnetation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

Comment: You mean so that onStop of the Activity gets called after the onBackPressed is handled? If so, that is implicitly a part of the polling, but I have tried it various ways already, I just don't get the flag from the meTask, e.g.:
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cancelling Task", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            while ((meTask.isRunning) && (i < 200)) {
                i++;
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "meTask  " + meTask.getStatus());
            meTask = null;
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;

Comment: You can also stop in onDestroy() and onPause()

Comment: @D_K I tried that, but run into the same problem, the task never executes onCancelled properly or at all, I have no way of polling for it being "done".

Comment: Try like this getApplicationContext().unbindService(serviceConnection);

also you bind service like this

Comment: @D_K The service does not seem to be the problem, or does it in your opinion? It's the AsyncTask that I can't cancel.

Comment: did you call meTask.cancel(true)?

Comment: @frestoinc Yep, that's in cancelTask(); which exists for historic reasons, as I've tried a lot of complicated wordarounds...I edited the question to show the method.